# How to css table not apply on image caption

Tags: html, css

I am using a css style for the table. But image html code and image caption also use tables.
This is code for the regular table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This is code for the image caption:

```
<table class="caption-container"><tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="link-image"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="caption">Caption text</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This mis my css:

```
table {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);
}

table td{padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);}
```

Is there any way for this css to apply to text tables only? Please help me!! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add to the text table: `class="text-table"` 
in the way that it reads like:

```
<table class="text-table">
```

and in the css change this

```css
table {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);
}

table td{padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);}
```

to this:

```css
.text-table {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);
}

.text-table td{padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);}
```

and you will achieve what you are asking for

OR, if you only want to exclude one class and only from the CSS, you can: put the css like:

```css
table:not(.caption-container) {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);
}

table:not(.caption-container) td{padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187,187,187);}
```

Comment: @ThànhNamNguyễn , Just edited my answer so you have how to do it only trough css!